# Data in X axis from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have some data that I want to plot. I'm using the code below:

```
import pandas_datareader as web

crypto_currency = 'BTC'
against_currency = 'USD'
start, end = dt.datetime(2012,1,1), dt.datetime.now()

df = web.DataReader(f'{crypto_currency}-{against_currency}', 'yahoo', start, end)
df.head()
```

The dataframe looks like this,

[image]

If for example, I want to plot the close values, I do the following:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="whitegrid")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

close_values = df.filter(['Close']).values

plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
plt.plot(close_values, label=f'Close values')

plt.xlim(0, len(close_values))
plt.title(f'{crypto_currency}-{against_currency} close data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

and the graph looks like this:

[image]

It's ok but I would like to show the date on X-axis. I thought I just have to obtain the date values from the index and add them as the X-axis, but it's wrong. Am I coding it wrong or is it conceptually wrong? I know it should be easy but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the `Date` as index, just plot the `df['Close']` right away.

```py
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="whitegrid")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
df['Close'].plot(title=f'{crypto_currency}-{against_currency} close data', label='Close values')

plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.xlabel('')
plt.show()
```

[image]

And if you use **`Date` data as index**, it is possible to search yearly, monthly, and daily.

```py
new_df = df['2020']
new_df

# df['2020-01':'2020-12'] --monthly
# df['2020-01-01':'2020-12-31'] --daily
```

[image]

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
new_df['Close'].plot(title=f'2020 {crypto_currency}-{against_currency} close data')

plt.xlabel('')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found that matplotlib can sometime be a bit picky with dates - without seeing the exact data format, if it is in a `pandas` format, you could try turning them intro strings first and then set the `xticks` directly:

```py
plt.xticks(list(df.index.astype(str)), list(df.index.astype(str)), rotation=30)
```